# Variable Argument list with no named argument?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Is it possible to have a function with variable arguments and no named argument?

For example:

```
SomeLogClass("Log Message Here %d").Log(5);
SomeLogClass("Log Message Here %d").Error(5);
```

Comment: Your examples don't require variadic function declarations at all.  Perhaps you could show us the declarations you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [QString's arg](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstring.html#arg) methods. Those seem to be something you're looking for.

You can definitely roll your own, although implementation might turn out to be not really trivial, especially if you would like it to support printf format specifiers. If printf style is not necessary, chaining a `replace_all` kind of calls sounds doable.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of doing it that way.

Comment: I really like this, it cleverly avoids the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Can you write code like that above - yes you can. But you cannot portable write a variadic function without at least one non-variadic parameter. In printf(), for example, this is the format string. In other words, you can write function s like:

```
int printf( const char * format, ... );
```

but not:

```
int printf( ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

Where I am from we use this:

```
Log << "LogMessageHere: " << ErrorClass << 5 << whatever << std::endl;
```

It is not exactly an answer to you question, but it is a solution to your problem, and I think it is more c++ like.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is no, you can't define only variable arguments, because the mechanism in C/C++ to do so uses a fixed argument in order to compute an address, like this:

```
void f(int a, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a); // without a, this macro DOESN'T WORK!!!


}
```

The answer you flagged gets around it by defaulting the arguments.  But what this should teach the newbies is that defaulting the arguments doesn't mean that arguments aren't passed, it means that you don't have to type them.

```
void f (int a = 0, ...)
```

So when you call f you can write:

```
f();
```

but internally, it's writing f(0)